# Issue when connecting Talend to FTP server

Tags: ftp, sftp, etl, talend

I am able to connect to the FTP server from the FileZilla successfully but when connecting through Talend, I am getting the following error message.

```
Starting job Ftp01 at 14:35 29/12/2016.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3903
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tFTPConnection_1
com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.ControlChannelIOException: Control channel unexpectedly closed ('' read so far)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.readLine(FTPControlSocket.java:1058)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.readReply(FTPControlSocket.java:1124)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.validateConnection(FTPControlSocket.java:444)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.<init>(FTPControlSocket.java:410)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.<init>(FTPControlSocket.java:381)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.connect(FTPClient.java:1037)
    at chc_etl_project.ftp01_0_1.Ftp01.tFTPConnection_1Process(Ftp01.java:378)
    at chc_etl_project.ftp01_0_1.Ftp01.runJobInTOS(Ftp01.java:1626)
    at chc_etl_project.ftp01_0_1.Ftp01.main(Ftp01.java:1483)
[statistics] disconnected
Job Ftp01 ended at 14:36 29/12/2016. [exit code=1]
```

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the tFTPConnection's settings ?

Comment: are you using the same box for both your Talend and FileZilla connection?  I am referring to the client computer, not the server.  If different boxes then you may have a firewall problem that is affecting only the Talend box.